# c++ program shuts down in windows comparing a char to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, chars

I have this part in the program

```
    char size_input[5]={'1','0','4','-'};
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
    cin >> size_input[i];
    if(size_input[i]!=char(45)){
        valid_size_characters++;
    }else{
        i=6;
    }
}
```

It compiles with no error  in both windows and linux but in windows when the program reaches that part it just crashes and I have no idea why

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Change `i<6` to `i<5` in the for loop condition.

Comment: You're not comparing a char to an array, like you say in the title. You're comparing two chars.

Comment: If you by `char(45)` mean the ASCII encoding for `'-'` then use the character instead of a [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: As for your problem, think a little. What is the valid range of indexes for an array of five elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an off-by-one error because your array has a size of 5 while the loop runs 6 times resulting in writing out of the array bounds causing undefined behavior. So it should be `i<5` instead of `i<6`.

Also avoid exiting the loop by manipulating the loop index `i`, instead you could use `break`.